# mysql if exists return value otherwise retuen ZERo (or whatever to indentify)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, exists

I have a MySQL DB with one simple table...

id(key), messageid, time

I need a query that if i pass the messageid it will give me back the message id if it exists. otherwise any other value like 0.

I have tried "EXISTS"  in various formulas but it either get 0 or 1.
If it exists, I need the messageid for further processing.

Thank you all.
DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *sounds* like you simply need:

```
select case when exists 
  (select * from t where messageId = <value>) 
then <value> else 0 end as messageId;
```